# How to find out the /SUBSYSTEM value of the client executable?

Tags: windows, linker, console, subsystem

I have a Windows DLL library which can be used by different client applications, both GUI and console. Is there a way to find out programmatically the client application type? I am not interested in if there is actually a console attached or not.

Comment: Always avoid finding info the hard way when the client app can trivially tell you.

Comment: Besides, the actual type of the executable may not accurately represent the way the executable is used, and any change in behaviour as a result may come as a very nasty surprise to the programmer.  Consider, for example, a [GUI application whose debug build is a console executable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23943220/886887).

Comment: Maybe I should have been less specific in my question, it seems this one is not so trivially answerable as I hoped. My real goal is to find out if e.g. stdout is in invalid state. In case of a console app the stdout is initialized correctly, whereas in a case of a GUI program stdout is left in an invalid state unless the application fixes it as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105305. The _get_osfhandle() function seems to return what appears to be an undocumented error code -2 for _fileno(stdout) if stdout is invalid, but as this is undocumented I am not sure how much I can rely on it.